# Make Ubuntu open a window in files when plugging in an external drive

Tags: 20.04, usb, hard-drive, nautilus, external-hdd

When I plug in an external hard drive, or a USB Drive, I get a notification that tells me it has been plugged in. If I hover over it with the mouse, it shows me a prompt to 'Open with Files' (aka Nautilus or whatever you have as the default File Manager). What I want is for Ubuntu to open this directory out of the box when I plug any drive (USB, external) in, or at least a way to "navigate" to the notification to open it without using the mouse. If someone knows how to do this, I'd be grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this would be via dconf-editor.

1. Open dconf-editor
2. Search for `automount-open`
3. Ensure the toggle is set to "true"
   [image: dconf-editor]

Alternatively, if you prefer using the terminal, you can do this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open true
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: I already have it like this. It does not do anything when mounting USB Drives nor External Drives.

Comment: That is why I asked matigo whether this is tested: it indeed does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to the notification with the keyboard and open the directory, hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Gnome-Shell apparently does not anymore support directly running a command when connecting USB or data driver that it is not recognized as something specific, e.g. an audio CD, Photo's, etc. For me, the setting `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open` does not make a difference.

Comment: Automount-open does indeed not make a difference. But I haven't been able to navigate to the notification with 'Super + M' either. Any ideas? Should I set it to some command in Shortcuts?

Comment: In a default Ubuntu install (and also default Gnome), both Super+M or Super+V open the notifications pane. You must have changed something.

Comment: In fact, Super+V is set as 'Show the notification list' in 'Keyboard Shortcuts' in settings... yet it won't work. Could it be 'Dash to Panel' is making it malfunction?

Comment: No idea. For me it always works, both in Ubuntu session and in gnome session.